# install %%R cell magic in docker from jupyter docker stack

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, ipython, rpy2

I tried installing the [datascience jupyter docker image](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-datascience-notebook) (tag 45b8529a6bfc, last update Feb 14, 2019) from docker stacks.  My entire dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:45b8529a6bfc
USER $NB_UID
```

When I open a new Jupyter notebook with an R kernel, the notebook works fine.  When I try a %%R cell magic in an ipython notebook, it doesn't work:

```
%%R
3+4
UsageError: Cell magic `%%R` not found.
```

I wandered around various stackoverflow answers and internet searches, tried installing rpy2 (it was already installed).  Didn't work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` as suggested by @lgautier, and got the error message `No module named 'simplegeneric'`. Once I pip installed simplegeneric, everything works and I don't need the `load_ext` statement.

Not sure why the dockerfile doesn't install simplegeneric, but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Load the jupyter extension before you try to use it:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer didn't work, but it led me to the answer.